# Search XML file using Linq for ID and return name

Tags: c#, xml, linq

In the following dummy XML file, I have to find search string in the stepContent node and return the ElementID and stepID. I am using Linq in C#, while I am able to find the search string and return the entire node, I am unable to figure out how to return the stepID and ElementID of searched node. Please note this is dummy XML and depths of these ID nodes may vary, so I need something to query them on names in the returned values.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <Elements>
        <Element>
            <ElementID>A001</ElementID>
            <Detail><![CDATA[<ul>
            <li>
              For top candidates
            </li>
            <li>
              Discount upto 50%
            </li>
          </ul>]]></Detail>
            <Steps>
                <Step>
                    <stepID>S001</stepID>
                    <StepHeading>Prepare for top candidates</StepHeading>
                    <stepContent><![CDATA[<ul>
                <li>Some dummy text</li>
                <li>Plan some dummy items.</li>
              </ul>]]></stepContent>
                </Step>
                <Step>
                    <stepID>S002</stepID>
                    <StepHeading>Invite top candidates</StepHeading>
                    <stepContent><![CDATA[<ul>
                <li>Dummy text for invitation.</li>
                <li>Dummy text for 2nd invitation.</li>

              </ul>]]></stepContent>
                </Step>
            </Steps>
        </Element>
        <Element>
            <ElementID>A002</ElementID>
            <Detail><![CDATA[<ul>
            <li>
              For next set of top candidates
            </li>
            <li>
              Discount upto 30%
            </li>
          </ul>]]></Detail>
            <Steps>
                <Step>
                    <stepID>S003</stepID>
                    <StepHeading>Prepare for next set of top candidates</StepHeading>
                    <stepContent><![CDATA[<ul>
                <li>Some dummy text</li>
                <li>Plan some dummy items.</li>
              </ul>]]></stepContent>
                </Step>
                <Step>
                    <stepID>S004</stepID>
                    <StepHeading>Invite next set of top candidates</StepHeading>
                    <stepContent><![CDATA[<ul>
                <li>Dummy text for invitation.</li>
                <li>Dummy text for 2nd invitation.</li>

              </ul>]]></stepContent>
                </Step>
            </Steps>
        </Element>
    </Elements>
</Root>
```

Comment: string xmlPath = Server.MapPath("myXMLPath.xml");
            var xml = XDocument.Load(@xmlPath);
            XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml.ToString());
            var resultNodes = xDocument.Descendants("stepContent").Where(i => i.Value.ToLower().Contains(searchString));


How do I get the ID from the result set now?

Comment: [edit] the question and put your C# code there (separate code block from your XML)

Answer (score 0):

> *"I have to find search string in the `stepContent` node and return the `ElementID` and `stepID`"*

As long as relative depth of `ElementID` and `stepID` from `stepContent` is consistent, you can do this way :

```
resultNodes.Select(o => new YourModelClass()
            {
                stepId = (string)o.Parent.Element("stepID"), 
                elementId = (string)o.Parent.Parent.Parent.Element("ElementID")
                //alternatively :
                //elementId = (string)o.Ancestors("Element").First().Element("ElementID")
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this way.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);

var steps = doc.Root.Descendants("Step")
    .Where(e=> ((string)e.Element("stepContent").Value).ToLower().Contains("dummy text for "))
    .Select(s=> new 
            { 
                StepId = s.Element("stepID").Value, 
                StepHeading = s.Element("stepID").Value
            });
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w2ZgZu)